# Suitable input type for java bytecode generator in asm lib

Tags: java, assembly, compiler-construction, java-bytecode-asm, jflex

Creating a java compiler.
Using jflex - lexical analysis, cup - parsing and asm- bytecode generation.
jlex output is a scanner object. We create a parser object to do the parsing.
What should we pass to the bytecode generation.
Is there any bytecode generation sample tutorial for asm where we can use to generate normal java bytecodes for any given java file?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Alexey. I read that. It is an example to generate a class which has hard coded. Do you know how we can generate bytecodes when input java source can be changed.

Comment: Did you read [*this*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html)? If, after reading this chapter, you still don’t know how to begin, I’m afraid that SO is not the right place to give a tutorial for such a complex topic…

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to get started is just following the advice here: [How do I start using ASM?](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q0)

It helps you to see what kind of ASM code would be needed to generate the same bytecode as a compiled java file. For me it would be all I need as I could write any construct in java and (following the above instructions) see how to generate the same using ASM, and then just modify it to suit my needs.